# css file being read regardless of changing url (css NOT cached)

Tags: css, subdirectory

Testing in Incognito / Chrome (to force non caching of files I wish to change / develop), the following keeps happening so I was hoping someone could please tell me why:

A php file is referencing and external file in path '../../../style.css' - the file is verified as read.

The path in the php file is CHANGED to: './style.css'; then to: '../../style.css' and no matter how many variations on number of sub-folders it is STILL read.

Non caching has been verified by changing the actual filename to:'styles.css (added s on the end) and the file read fails with a resulting unstyled page.

Can someone please point out why changing the number of sub-folders appears to have NO effect.

Many thanks
Will

Many tests in a non-caching environment.

Comment: Have you tried `/../../../style.css`? 

Comment: What is the URL of the file in which you have the `../../../style.css`  to load the css file?

Comment: Thanks deEr... do you mean add / right at the beginning of ../../../ etc so it becomes /../../../?

Comment: Thanks t.niese ... OK, so the php file calling the css file is in root/cats/landing/ and the css file is in root/css/ therefore inside the php file I point to the css file using ../ (back to cats) ../ (back to root) var/style.css ... the problem I have is the css file is found regardless of how many ../ I use. It will see the css file whether I use ../ or ../../../../../../ 

Comment: While caching is most likely not your problem, I think it's worth mentioning that incognito does not use a separate caching mechanism. A file cached while in normal browsing will still be cached in incognito.

Comment: As a general tip: Never use relative paths. It's much easier to reference style sheets (and all resources in general) using their absolute path beginning with `/`.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to determine the root cause of the problem without seeing the actual code.

Likely, you have discovered that any relative reference to a file above the root will be resolved to the root itself.

If for example, we have these files below, the text will be blue. Note that both files are located directly in the root, but `index.html` references `style.css` two levels above it.

### /index.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../style.css" />
<div>Look at me, I am blue!</div>
```

### /style.css

```css
div {
  color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, together we've nailed it. :)

Comment: @willemdebeer Happy to help! Please upvote this answer and click the "tick" symbol to "Mark as answer". That'll make it clear for other people visiting this page how to resolve the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was locating the css file relative to the location of the file 'calling' it...

Back to sub-folder, sub-folder, sub-folder then  up into folder 'css'.

../../../css/

It appears the path needs to be relative to the root, NOT the file containing the path.

Simply /css

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Any path that starts with `.` or `..` is relative to the path of the file where that statement is written. However, if you use enough `../` sequences then you will always be referencing from the point of view of the root because you can't go "above" the root. If you start a path with `/` then it is an absolute path, meaning it is located from the point of view of the root.

Comment: If you have found a solution to your question, best to update the original question with your solution instead.